# Linear transformation over fields

Tags: linear-algebra

Please give an example of a linear transformation over an arbitrary field.
Please explain as well, thank you.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map#Examples

Answer (score 1):

Over **any** field $\,\Bbb F\,$, the next are  linear transformations:

$$f(x)=0\;,\;\;\forall x\in\Bbb F\;\;;\;\;\;g(x)=kx\;,\;\;\text{for fixed}\;k\in\Bbb F\,\,\,\wedge\,\,\,\forall\,x\in F$$

It's not hard to show that any linear transformation $\,\Bbb F\to\Bbb F\,$ is of the general form as $\,g(x)\,$ above...if one knows some linear algebra, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Take any field $F$ and any algebra $A$ over $F$. Choose $a\in A$. Then the map $x\mapsto ax$ is a $F$-linear transformation of $A$.

For instance, let $A=F^{n\times n}$, the algebra of $n\times n$ matrices with entries in $F$ and let $a$ be any matrix.